# A successful build is needed before the preview can be displayed or can not show content in preview in Android Studio 4.0 (Canary)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-4.0

I have tried to open the preview, but I can not open it.

I have tried opening Android Studio again, but the preview shows only a blank white screen and no content is shown inside it.
When I open it again, it shows the following message at the preview side:

```
A successful build is needed before the preview can be displayed
```

A Build process has been finished and tried to build multiple times but still showing the same error.

I have used simple text inside it.

```
    @Composable
    fun Greeting(name: String) {
        Text (text = "Hello $name!")
    }
```

Here is my full content:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Greeting("Android")
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Greeting(name: String) {
        Text (text = "Hello $name!")
    }

    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun PreviewGreeting() {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ... are you talking about the layout preview, which just displays XML or you're trying to run the app and make your code run?

Comment: I am trying to show content in Preview which is at the right side, after giving the annotation @Preview.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Greeting("Android")
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Greeting(name: String) {
        Text (text = "Hello $name!")
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewGreeting() {
    Greeting("Android")
}
```

Comment: How `PreviewGreeting()` function calls `Greeting()` class member method of MainActivity? That should not be possible within the rules of Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. The build error message I got when I clicked on **"Run with --info"** was:

> e: This version (1.0.0-alpha13) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.30 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

So I went to the **project level** *build.gradle* file and added a snippet before the changes (you may change the version according to your error message) -

```
buildscript {
    ..
    ..
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    ..
    ..
}
```

So according to the error message, I changed ***kotlin-gradle-plugin*** version from 1.5.0 to 1.4.30 as below:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"
```

to

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
```

After this again, I did 'Sync Now' the Gradle file and did 'Build & Refresh' in the preview tab. Hopefully the **compatibility issues** were gone and I was able to see the real time preview.

This may not be the best solution as we it requires downgrading Kotlin version, but yeah it worked for me. You can just try it off!!

Comment: Could you be more specific where to add the "--info" option?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the developer's document carefully. Please *define* your greeting function and PreviewGreeting function outside the MainActivity. Please do something like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.Composable
import androidx.compose.unaryPlus
import androidx.ui.core.Text
import androidx.ui.core.dp
import androidx.ui.core.setContent
import androidx.ui.foundation.DrawImage
import androidx.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.ui.layout.*
import androidx.ui.material.MaterialColors
import androidx.ui.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.ui.res.imageResource
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme(
                colors = MaterialColors(
                    primary = Color.Black,
                    background = Color.Cyan,
                    secondary = Color.Magenta
                )
            ) {
                Greeting("Hello World")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)

    Column(crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand, modifier = Spacing(16.dp)) {
        Text(name)
        Text(name)
        Text(name)
        HeightSpacer(50.dp)
        Container(expanded = true, height = 100.dp, width = 100.dp) {
            DrawImage(image)
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)

    Column(crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand, modifier = Spacing(16.dp)) {
        Text("Android")
        Text("Android")
        Text("Android")
        Text("Hello")
        HeightSpacer(50.dp)
        Container(expanded = true, height = 100.dp, width = 100.dp) {
            DrawImage(image)
        }
    }
}
```

And then run your app one time in the device/emulator. Then you can see the preview working:

[image]

Comment: No, still not showing preview from my side with this as well.

Comment: A word of advice if you're following a jetpack compose tutorial and having issues, the google codelab one is the most up to date and the one you should follow https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps, worked for me:

1. File -> Invalid Caches/Restart
2. Click on the preview screen, where it says "A successful build is needed before..."
3. Build & Refresh with the following command: Option + Command + Shift + R (on Mac), I guess Alt + Ctrl + Shift + R is the command on Windows

It is important to click on the preview screen before you run the command.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, invalidate cache and restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have fixed it already, but would still answer as there is no accepted answer yet.

I tried creating project from `Empty Compose Activity` project template. and It shows above error.

There is an issue in `app:build.gradle` file.

Replace `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'` with `compileSdkVersion 
29`

Replace `targetSdkVersion 23` with `targetSdkVersion 29`

Clean and build the project and issues should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After you build, close the file and then reopen it from the file tree on the left. Then it should work. I have no preview in there, so now it says *no* preview found. Add a preview by annotation *compostables* with @Preview.

But I think it will work for you.

Comment: Is it really "compostables"? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66373848/edit) a reference to documentation? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me when the error was version `1.8.10` and I had `1.9.0` installed,
I went to `build.gradle.kts`
and directly change the String
I had `1.9.0` for `1.8.10`, that worked

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of weird when you first create your compose project the preview doesn't work. A very simple solution is just go to the *Build* → *Rebuild* menu to rebuild your project and everything just works fine :)

[Image Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA3Kx.png)